# How to remove vertical spacing below mdframed boxes?

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I've set `skipbelow=0pt`. I still have vertical spacing below every box. I think this has to do with the paragraph spacing. Is there a way to disable this for `mdframed`? I'd like to avoid using `\vspace{-5pt}` after every box, since this makes behave my `multicols` layout weird (page breaks in the middle of the page).

How can I get rid of the spacing after every box? (Disable new line? Disable paragraph spacing just for `mdframed` boxes? ...)

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{myframe}{%
    outerlinewidth=1pt,
    skipabove=0pt,
    skipbelow=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=myframe]
Hello
\end{mdframed}
% Annoying space in between, despite skipabove=skipbelow=0pt
\begin{mdframed}[style=myframe]
Hello
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Space between two instances of a self-defined environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69651/5764)

Comment: Unfortunately the answer there only suggests to set skipablove=skipbelow=0pt which I already did. Furthermore, mdframed is not a self-defined environment

Comment: It's related, not necessary a duplicate/solution. You can also set `skipbelow` to a negative value...

Comment: I've tried that - values below 0 had no effect. It seems to be a paragraph spacing or something.

Comment: Is the code above producing the error? If I compile it I get two boxes without any space in between. Is your system up to date?

Comment: Try adding `\unskip` at the end of the environment.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174587/mdframed-vertical-space-difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting skipabove and skipbelow to 0pt globaly with the `\mdfsetup` command does the trick (mdframed version 1.9b).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt}

\mdfdefinestyle{myframe}{%
    outerlinewidth=1pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=myframe]
Hello
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=myframe]
Hello
\end{mdframed}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! The approach of Steven B. Segelets with `\unskip` also works. However, with Seven's approach, if one still wants to have some exact amount of space greater than 0, then one needs to add `\vskip ...pt` after `\unskip`.

Comment: Any idea why setting it globally works but setting it just for a specific environment doesn't?